# Retreive error message in session$onSessionEnded

Tags: shiny

Before my app closes, I would like to log on a file if app has close with or without error.

Ideally I would like to set my 2 variables :

- `error` as Boolean (error or not)
- `errorMessage` as character (error message)

My example :

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
      mainPanel(
         actionButton("works","Exit without error")
         ,actionButton("error","Exit with error")
      )
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
    session$onSessionEnded(function() {
        # Herebelow my 2 variables I want to set dynamically :
        error = TRUE
        errorMessage =  "my error"
        if (error) {
          write(x = paste("App has temrinated with error :",errorMessage), file = "./myLogFile.txt", append = TRUE)
        } else {
          write(x = "App has terminated without error", file = "./myLogFile.txt", append = TRUE)
        }
    })

    observeEvent(input$works, {
      stopApp()
    })

    observeEvent(input$error, {
      function_that_doesnt_exist()
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Edit :

When I set `options(shiny.error = browser)` I get the variable `e` which is exactly what I'm looking for (see picture below).
But I can't get it in `session$onSessionEnded`

[image]